Why are modules' resource files required in a WPF PRISM application?
I am developing a modularized, loosely coupled WPF application with PRISM framework. Modules are discovered using a directory.
Even without using any icon, file or any other resource (unless I'm not doing that intentionally), I am getting the following exception when launching the application:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\repos\JCT\JCT_JarvisConfigTool\JCT.UI\bin\x86\Debug\net8.0-windows\Modules\MainContent.resources.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

This happens for each of the modules, the file not found is .resources.dll. Of course, the file does not exist since I am not creating any resource file.
This exception is not enabled for breaking by default in Visual Studio, but you can still see the message in the output.
I understand that text in te buttons for example could be a resource, but I'm not sure why the those files are required.
I have tried forcing the resource creation from the project properties:

but it was not helping, resource files didn't get created. Then I forced resource creation by editing the project file, adding resource for en-US, and it worked. In any case, I don't think that's the best solution, I also don't have any type of control about what is inside this resource file.
I downloaded a demo application using the Prism templates, and it runs without asking for the resource.
Of course there is a lack of knowledge from my side here but I can't find the explanation for this behavior nor the solution.
Any hint will be welcomed.

what does your csproj files look like? is there any <Localizable> or <UICulture> tag in there? if you get this exception, there's a satellite assembly in the output somewhere, i.e. in a subdirectory like en  or de. those should be deployed and available at runtime.

There is no <Localizable> or <UICulture> tag in my csproj files.
I also forgt t mention that if I ignore the exception, I don't notice anything wrong, all looks to work properly
